# Having trouble the .equals in JAVA

Tags: java

```
package thenewboston;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class apple {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first num");
        double fnum, snum, answer;
        String oper;
        fnum = myScan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your second num");
        snum = myScan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your operation");
        if (oper.equals("+")) {
        answer = fnum + snum;
        } else if (oper.equals("-")){
            answer = fnum - snum;
        } else if (oper.equals("*")) {
            answer = fnum * snum;
        } else if (oper.equals("/")){
            answer = fnum / snum;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please choose a valid operation");
        }
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);
    }

}
```

Hi. Im trying to use .equals() in order to create a basic calculator but there is an error showing up on oper when I write oper.equals("...").

Comment: Post your *complete* error messages here please as this is critical information.

Comment: You never assign `oper` to anything.

Comment: `"but there is an error showing up "` - The first step in correcting an error is *reading the error message*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @David He would not get an NPE. He would get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign value to **oper**.

```
String oper = "*";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an error because you never actually set `oper` to anything before using it.

```
...
snum = myScan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter your operation");
oper = myScan.nextLine(); //<-- You were missing this.
if (oper.equals("+")) {
answer = fnum + snum;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask the user to input an operation, therefore, your oper can't match any of the things you say later.